# AWS S3 Node.js SDK: Need to Download all files from one bucket at once

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I can iterate over all files in bucket and download one by one,
using node.js sdk.
I need to download all files from S3 bucket at once. then remove it from bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This higher-level Node S3 library has a `downloadDir` function which syncs a remote S3 bucket with a local directory.

https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client#clientdownloaddirparams

Comment: This library is obsolete.

Comment: I recommend using [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) instead, which is maintained by Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `aws cli` using the command below:

```
aws s3 sync s3://yourbucket .
```

If you have to use `node` then you can use `exec` or `spwan`.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('aws s3 sync s3://yourbucket .', (err, stdout, stderr) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function `listFiles` that returns an array of the Keys in the bucket you want to download and a function `downloadFile` that accepts a file Key (name) and downloads it and then deletes it.

You want to call `downloadFile` simultaneously on all files returned from `listFiles` right? Use the `async` library.

```
function listFiles(cb) {
    s3.stuff(params, cb);
}
function downlaodFile(key, cb) {
    s3.stuff(key, cb);
}
listFiles(function (err, fileKeys) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;//don't really but this is just an example
    }
    async.each(fileKeys, downloadFile, function done(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm already download the files one be one. I'm searching for approach to download the bucket in one shoot .. something like [downloadBucket() or transferBucket() ..etc]

Comment: That functionality doesn't exist in S3